# grok: where do I define custom grok tags

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to parse nginx log using Logstash, I found out this question:

[Nginx grok pattern for logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211469/nginx-grok-pattern-for-logstash)

I want to try the pattern in the question, so I create the configuration file with this content:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    type => "access"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:ident} %{NGUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|-)\"%{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{NOTSPACE:querystring} (?:"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)"|%{QS:referrer})%{QS:agent}  %{IPORHOST:forwardedfor} %{IPORHOST:host} %{NUMBER:upstreamresponse} (?:-|%{NUMBER:cache})'
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
}
```

But I get the error:

```
[2021-03-24T13:25:53,424][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{NGUSER:ident} not defined>, :backtrace=>["/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:123:in `block in compile'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1442:in `loop'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:93:in `compile'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.0/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:282:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809:in `each'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.0/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:276:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1415:in `each'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.0/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:271:in `register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractFilterDelegatorExt.java:75:in `register'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:228:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809:in `each'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:227:in `register_plugins'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:586:in `maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:240:in `start_workers'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:185:in `run'", "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:137:in `block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.12.0/config/pipeline.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x175b972c run>"}
```

In this particular case, I want to make `NGUSER` equal to `[a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+`

So there comes my question: Where do I define custom grok tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern_definitions option to the grok filter

```
grok {
    pattern_definition => {
        "NGUSER" => "[a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+"
    }
    match => { "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:ident} %{NGUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|-)\"%{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{NOTSPACE:querystring} (?:"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)"|%{QS:referrer})%{QS:agent}  %{IPORHOST:forwardedfor} %{IPORHOST:host} %{NUMBER:upstreamresponse} (?:-|%{NUMBER:cache})' }
}
```

or, if you think you might want to share the patterns across multiple instances you can use the patterns_dir option

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => [ "/home/user/patterns/" ]
    match => { "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:ident} %{NGUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|-)\"%{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{NOTSPACE:querystring} (?:"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)"|%{QS:referrer})%{QS:agent}  %{IPORHOST:forwardedfor} %{IPORHOST:host} %{NUMBER:upstreamresponse} (?:-|%{NUMBER:cache})' }
}
```

and create a file in that directory that contains

```
NGUSER [a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+
```